# How configure properly Grafana Tempo?

Tags: spring-cloud, grafana, spring-cloud-sleuth, jaeger, distributed-tracing

I tried to use Grafana Tempo for distributed tracing.

I launch it from docker-compose:

```
version: "3.9"
services:

  # MY MICROSERVICES
  ...

  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - ${PROMETHEUS_EXTERNAL_PORT}:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml:cached

  promtail:
    image: grafana/promtail
    volumes:
      - ./log:/var/log
      - ./promtail/:/mnt/config
    command: -config.file=/mnt/config/promtail-config.yaml

  loki:
    image: grafana/loki
    command: -config.file=/etc/loki/local-config.yaml

  tempo:
    image: grafana/tempo
    command: [ "-config.file=/etc/tempo.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - ./tempo/tempo-local.yaml:/etc/tempo.yaml
      # - ./tempo-data/:/tmp/tempo
    ports:
      - "14268"  # jaeger ingest
      - "3200"   # tempo
      - "55680"  # otlp grpc
      - "55681"  # otlp http
      - "9411"   # zipkin

  tempo-query:
    image: grafana/tempo-query
    command: [ "--grpc-storage-plugin.configuration-file=/etc/tempo-query.yaml" ]
    volumes:
      - ./tempo/tempo-query.yaml:/etc/tempo-query.yaml
    ports:
      - "16686:16686"  # jaeger-ui
    depends_on:
      - tempo

  grafana:
    image: grafana/grafana
    volumes:
      - ./grafana/datasource-config/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/datasources:cached
      - ./grafana/dashboards/prometheus.json:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/prometheus.json:cached
      - ./grafana/dashboards/loki.json:/var/lib/grafana/dashboards/loki.json:cached
      - ./grafana/dashboards-config/:/etc/grafana/provisioning/dashboards:cached
    ports:
      - ${GRAFANA_EXTERNAL_PORT}:3000
    environment:
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
      - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Admin
      - GF_AUTH_DISABLE_LOGIN_FORM=true
    depends_on:
      - prometheus
      - loki
```

with `tempo-local.yaml`:

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 3200

distributor:
  receivers:                           # this configuration will listen on all ports and protocols that tempo is capable of.
    jaeger:                            # the receives all come from the OpenTelemetry collector.  more configuration information can
      protocols:                       # be found there: https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/tree/main/receiver
        thrift_http:                   #
        grpc:                          # for a production deployment you should only enable the receivers you need!
        thrift_binary:
        thrift_compact:
    zipkin:
    otlp:
      protocols:
        http:
        grpc:
    opencensus:

ingester:
  trace_idle_period: 10s               # the length of time after a trace has not received spans to consider it complete and flush it
  max_block_bytes: 1_000_000           # cut the head block when it hits this size or ...
  max_block_duration: 5m               #   this much time passes

compactor:
  compaction:
    compaction_window: 1h              # blocks in this time window will be compacted together
    max_block_bytes: 100_000_000       # maximum size of compacted blocks
    block_retention: 1h
    compacted_block_retention: 10m

storage:
  trace:
    backend: local                     # backend configuration to use
    block:
      bloom_filter_false_positive: .05 # bloom filter false positive rate.  lower values create larger filters but fewer false positives
      index_downsample_bytes: 1000     # number of bytes per index record
      encoding: zstd                   # block encoding/compression.  options: none, gzip, lz4-64k, lz4-256k, lz4-1M, lz4, snappy, zstd, s2
    wal:
      path: /tmp/tempo/wal             # where to store the the wal locally
      encoding: snappy                 # wal encoding/compression.  options: none, gzip, lz4-64k, lz4-256k, lz4-1M, lz4, snappy, zstd, s2
    local:
      path: /tmp/tempo/blocks
    pool:
      max_workers: 100                 # worker pool determines the number of parallel requests to the object store backend
      queue_depth: 10000
```

`tempo-query.yaml`:

```
backend: "tempo:3200"
```

and `datasource.yml` for instrumenting datasources on grafana:

```
apiVersion: 1

deleteDatasources:
  - name: Prometheus
  - name: Tempo
  - name: Loki

datasources:

  - name: Prometheus
    type: prometheus
    access: proxy
    orgId: 1
    url: http://prometheus:9090
    basicAuth: false
    isDefault: false
    version: 1
    editable: false

  - name: Tempo
    type: tempo
    access: proxy
    orgId: 1
    url: http://tempo-query:16686
    basicAuth: false
    isDefault: false
    version: 1
    editable: false
    apiVersion: 1
    uid: tempo

  - name: Tempo-Multitenant
    type: tempo
    access: proxy
    orgId: 1
    url: http://tempo-query:16686
    basicAuth: false
    isDefault: false
    version: 1
    editable: false
    apiVersion: 1
    uid: tempo-authed
    jsonData:
      httpHeaderName1: 'Authorization'
    secureJsonData:
      httpHeaderValue1: 'Bearer foo-bar-baz'

  - name: Loki
    type: loki
    access: proxy
    orgId: 1
    url: http://loki:3100
    basicAuth: false
    isDefault: false
    version: 1
    editable: false
    apiVersion: 1
    jsonData:
      derivedFields:
        - datasourceUid: tempo
          matcherRegex: \[.+,(.+),.+\]
          name: TraceID
          url: $${__value.raw}
```

But if I test the datasource in grafana, I have this error:
[image]

In Loki view I can found the Tempo button for seeing traces... but I can't see it on Tempo because I have an error:
[image]

Anyway if I take the trace id and I search it on Jaeger, I can see it correctly.
[image]

What I missing in configuration for Tempo? How configure it correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Grafana 7.5 and later can talk to Tempo natively, and no longer need the tempo-query proxy.  I think this explains what is happening, Grafana is attempting to use the Tempo-native API against tempo-query, which exposes the Jaeger API instead.  Try changing the Grafana datasource in datasource.yml to `http://tempo:3200`.

Answer (score -1):

This solution applies to the tempo installation via the [kubernetes helm charts](https://grafana.github.io/helm-charts) (so it applies to the question's title but not the exact question):

Use the url `http://helmreleasename-tempo:3100` for configuring the tempo datasource in grafana. You need to check your tempo service name in kubernetes and use the port 3100.